# google.apps.sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsService.GetValues 100% errors 503 "The service is currently unavailable.","status":"UNAVAILABLE"

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-workspace

I'm facing strange behaviours from google sheet api v4 since saturday as I get 503 error almost 1O out of 10 when trying to update or append values through api. Here are some values from google sheet api console:

**Errors by API method** > google.apps.sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsService.GetValues:Value:100%
**Latency by API method (median)** > google.apps.sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsService.GetValues:Value:3.36min

**Methods**
google.apps.sheets.v4.SpreadsheetsService.GetValues:29 Requests
Errors:27.59%
Avg latency:53.826 seconds
99th percentile latency:4 minutes

The requested google sheet is quite volumic (13.1 MB) and contains some sheets where the largest is arround 30k lines and 10 columns - far above limitations documented from google - while others are cross-referenced with functions. However I did not build a rocket within it yet.

The weirdest thing here is that somehow the google sheet seems to block itself for a given period of time before receiving requests back and then reverts to a closed shell.

After investigating, it seems that the google sheet api is processing the request too slow and the request timed out generating the 503 error. Setting up retries on loop seems to make it work but the pace is not fast enough.

Does someone already faced this kind of issue and how did you manage to go through ?

***spoiler***: I already tried to split the google sheet in smallers sheets while reducing the number of formula cross-referenced but in the end it didn't impact the behaviour so far.

Many thanks for reading and taking time to assist!